# Parse Multi-Level JSON Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

JSON response -

```
{
  "001": {
    "STUDENTTYPE": {
      "TYPE": "Boarder"
    },
    "ACADEMICS": [
      {
        "SCI": 42,
        "MTH": 22
      },
      {
        "SCI": 49,
        "MTH": 36
      },
      {
        "SCI": 42,
        "MTH": 26
      }
    ],
    "ROLL": "001",
    "NAME": "Ben",
    "CLASS": "XI",
    "CLASSTEACHER": "Aka",
    "HOME": "Katrasgarh"
  },
  "002": {
    "STUDENTTYPE": {
      "TYPE": "DayScholar"
    },
    "ACADEMICS": [
      {
        "SCI": 43,
        "MTH": 24
      },
      {
        "SCI": 43,
        "MTH": 36
      },
      {
        "SCI": 47,
        "MTH": 28
      }
    ],
    "ROLL": "002",
    "NAME": "Bee",
    "CLASS": "XI",
    "CLASSTEACHER": "Ama",
    "HOME": "Kats"
  }
  ....
}
```

I am not able to fetch inner JSONs. Here is what I have done till now -

```
jsonLocation = sys.argv[1]
jsonFile = open(jsonLocation, 'rb')
jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)

for rollNo in jsonData:
print(rollNo)
for studentItems in jsonData[rollNo]:
     print(studentItems['ROLL'])
     print(studentItems['NAME'])
     print(studentItems['CLASS'])
     print(studentItems['CLASSTEATCHER'])
     print(studentItems['HOME'])
     print(studentItems['STUDENTTYPETYPE']['TYPE'])
```

I do get the values for each keys inside `studentItems` but this looks to me a clumpsy way to do it. I have also tried `json.dump` but it fails with error that JSON is non-serializable.
Is there a better way to iterate through this JSON format?

This is the Sample output I am looking for -

```
001:

001
Ben
XI
Aka
Katrasgarh

Boarder

42,22
49,36
42,26

002:

002
Bee
XI
Ama
Kats
..
.
```

Comment: Which keys do you want as the response, please add that into your question as well

Comment: The keys inside `studentItems`.

Comment: I am sorry, please can you update your question with a sample output

Comment: I have updated the output. I am not really concerned about the out put but the way in which the elements can be accessed properly.

Comment: The structure returned by `json.load` is a nested Python dict. To iterate over the keys, you iterate over the dict itself. To iterate over just the values, iterate over dict.values(). To iterate over the keys and values in pairs iterate over dict.items(). This last would look like `for key, value in jsonData[rollNo].items():`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear as to how you want the output to look, but I went ahead and just flattened out the nested json, then reconstruct it into a dataframe. From there you can access the data by slicing/filtering the table, write to a csv, or do whatever you'd like. But essentially each row will represent the `ROLL`, with the attributes, and the corresponding science and math scores with an index number starting at 0. If some students have a longer list within the `ACADEMICS` key, you'll have rows with nulls for students who had lest test scores.

**Given:**

```
jsonData = {
  "001": {
    "STUDENTTYPE": {
      "TYPE": "Boarder"
    },
    "ACADEMICS": [
      {
        "SCI": 42,
        "MTH": 22
      },
      {
        "SCI": 49,
        "MTH": 36
      },
      {
        "SCI": 42,
        "MTH": 26
      }
    ],
    "ROLL": "001",
    "NAME": "Ben",
    "CLASS": "XI",
    "CLASSTEACHER": "Aka",
    "HOME": "Katrasgarh"
  },
  "002": {
    "STUDENTTYPE": {
      "TYPE": "DayScholar"
    },
    "ACADEMICS": [
      {
        "SCI": 43,
        "MTH": 24
      },
      {
        "SCI": 43,
        "MTH": 36
      },
      {
        "SCI": 47,
        "MTH": 28
      }
    ],
    "ROLL": "002",
    "NAME": "Bee",
    "CLASS": "XI",
    "CLASSTEACHER": "Ama",
    "HOME": "Kats"
  }

}
```

**Code:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import re

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = flatten_json(jsonData)



results = pd.DataFrame()
columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    row_idx = re.findall(r'(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    column = item.replace(row_idx + '_', '')
    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
  STUDENTTYPE_TYPE  ACADEMICS_0_SCI  ACADEMICS_0_MTH  ACADEMICS_1_SCI  ACADEMICS_1_MTH  ACADEMICS_2_SCI  ACADEMICS_2_MTH ROLL NAME CLASS CLASSTEACHER        HOME
1          Boarder             42.0             22.0             49.0             36.0             42.0             26.0  001  Ben    XI          Aka  Katrasgarh
2       DayScholar             43.0             24.0             43.0             36.0             47.0             28.0  002  Bee    XI          Ama        Kats
```